# How can I get textContent of an element with line breaks? JavaScript - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension similar to Grammarly. Basically, I want to replace text inside gmail's compose box.
The problem I'm facing is, when I type something like "What's up?" in the compose box, it's adding some spans that shows grammar errors and other errors and it's going to look like this.

```
<span zeum4c5="PR_8_0" data-ddnwab="PR_8_0" aria-invalid="spelling" class="LI ng">
how
</span> 
do 
<span zeum4c5="PR_7_0" data-ddnwab="PR_7_0" aria-invalid="grammar" class="Lm ng">you do</span>
?
<div id="signatureDiv" class="signatureDiv"></div>
```

Even if this is a single sentence, I cannot replace the sentence without damaging this HTML tags. If I use

```
element.innerHTML.replace("how do you do", "some text");
```

it won't work because it cannot find something like that in innerHTML.

I can use element.textContent but it will remove the line brakes in the text.

So what are my options here?

Any comment will be helpful!

Comment: You should store the original text without the spans in a variable. And just create new HTML after each key is pressed and add it into the textbox.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski but it will remove all new lines I think

Comment: Try using `innerText` instead of `textContent`